# Does a tangential vector experience length contraction when moved in radial direction through Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, geometry

Let's have a look at the Schwarzschild solution. Let's consider only the spatial part since my question is only regarding length contraction.
There is the coefficient of the radial component, it's $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{2 M}{r}}$.

1. This leads to length contraction in the radial direction if a vector is moved from a larger radius to a smaller radius.
2. If a radial vector is moved, it experiences the highest amount of length contraction.

However, what about a tangential vector: Does it experience length contraction at all? If a tangential vector is moved, can it at all be distinguished whether it's moved in Euclidean space or in Schwarzschild metric - space?

And if a three-dimensional body is moved from a large radius to a smaller radius - does it change its ratio of height to length due to the fact that length contraction takes place only in the radial direction?

And, final question: Is that change in height-length ratio proven experimentally?

Comment: In relativity theory, objects don't "experience" length contraction or time dilation.

Comment: @JohnDoty and how would you express it?

Comment: The object is not moving in its own frame. It is unaffected by the state of motion of an observer in a frame moving relative to it.